# Scikit Learn SVR Learn does not iterate

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently trying to make a curve fit via SVR but without success. The model does not iterate and returns a vector with identical results. What can it be ?

```
def open_file_mod():
    data_f, data = [], []
    file = ["PDP1.3ddose", "OAR.3ddose", "PDP2.3ddose"]
    for i in range(3):
        data_f.append(open(file[i], 'r'))
        data.append(list(data_f[i].readlines()))
        data_f[i].close()
    
    return data[0], data[1], data[2]

def dose_processor(data, max_dose=None, min_depth=None):#, normalize=True, std_units=True):

    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        data[i] = d.split()

        # Mapping the values to cast them into floats
   
        data[i] = list(map(float, data[i]))
    
    doses = np.array(data[4]) # Doses
    if not max_dose or doses.max() > max_dose:
        max_dose = doses.max() # Getting the maximum dose

    error = np.array(data[5]) # Errors

    if data[0][0] == 1. and data[0][1] == 1.:
        depths = np.array(data[3])
        if not min_depth  or depths.min() < min_depth:
            min_depth = depths.min()
        depths -= min_depth
        depths = depths[:-1] + np.diff(depths)/2

        return depths, doses, error, min_depth, max_dose

    else:
        xis = np.array(data[1])
        xis = xis[:-1] + np.diff(xis)/2
        yps = np.array(data[2])
        yps = yps[:-1] + np.diff(yps)/2

        return xis, yps, doses, error


all_data = open_file_mod()

depths_pdp1, dose_pdp1, err_pdp1, min_depth, max_dose  = dose_processor(
        all_data[0]
)

xis_oar, yps_oar, dose_oar, err_oar = dose_processor(all_data[1])

depths_pdp2, dose_pdp2, err_pdp2, _, __ = dose_processor(
    all_data[2],
    max_dose,
    min_depth
)


xis, yps = np.meshgrid(xis_oar, yps_oar)
dose_oar = dose_oar.reshape((298,298))
```

The svr approach starts here.

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
custom_reg = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf')

depths_train , depths_test , doses_train, doses_test = train_test_split(
    depths_tot, 
    doses_tot, 
    test_size=.25, 
    random_state=0
)

depths_train= depths_train.reshape(-1,1)
custom_reg.fit(depths_train, doses_train)
```

And the predictor returns:

```
custom_reg.predict(depths_test.reshape(-1,1))
```

[OUT]:
array([1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15,
...
1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15, 1.49186219e-15,
1.49186219e-15])

Could someone help me indicate what might be going on?

Comment: Do `depths_train` and `doses_train` have the values you expect?  And how are `depths_tot` and `doses_tot` assigned?

Comment: I solved the problem by modifying the order of magnitude of my values. Before, they were between e-15 and e-16, multiplying by a factor of this magnitude the algorithm worked perfectly.